# Problem with behavior of subprocess.check_output function

Tags: python, subprocess, output

my code is:

```
import subprocess

answer = subprocess.check_output("python ../pydig/pydig @1.1.1.1 +tls=noauth goowdqdqdqdgle.de A",  encoding='utf8')
print (answer)
```

Pydig is a library to lookup domain names. The problem i have is when i execute this program it tells me a subprocess.CalledProcessError:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'python ../pydig/pydig @1.1.1.1 +tls=noauth goowdqdqdqdgle.de A' returned non-zero exit status 3.
```

But when i execute the command `pydig @1.1.1.1 +tls=noauth goowdqdqdqdgle.de A` via the command prompt it gives me a valid output.

How is that possible?

Thank you for helping.

Greetings

Comment: I don't get what u mean. If I use 'google.de' instead of 'goowdqdqdqdgle.de' as parameter in the subprocess.check_output function it works, so I don't know where the problem is that it won't excecute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) isn't going to yield the output of the command if the command fails.

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and any output in the output attribute.

Since the website doesn't exist, the command returns an error and all you get is a python exception. If you want to get the output anyway, use `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run` (python 3.5+) with output/error redirection.

Also always use list of arguments, not strings.

Example with `Popen`

```
handle = subprocess.Popen(["python","../pydig/pydig","@1.1.1.1","+tls=noauth","goowdqdqdqdgle.de","A"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE  encoding='utf8')
out,err = handle.communicate()
return_code = handle.wait()
print(return_code,out.decode(),err.decode())
```

note that since the command to run is a python code, you may replace the first `"python"` argument by `sys.executable` (so it runs with the same interpreter as your script) or find if it's not possible to import the module and call a function (avoids spawning a sub-process/preserves exception chain)

Comment: should you use `shell=True`?

Comment: not if you can avoid it as it creates an extra shell, interprets characters, and is unsafe.

Comment: I think i have a simple solution that fixed it:
`answer = subprocess.run("python ../pydig/pydig @1.1.1.1 +tls=noauth goowdqdqdqdgle.de A", encoding='utf8', capture_output=True)` with `answer.stdout` as the output.